# Bybit API Batch Place Order which logic behind?

Tags: bybit

Can anyone explain to me the logic of the Batch Place Order API?

The underlying logic should involve submitting more than one order simultaneously. To achieve this, a block of two or more orders is inserted into an array called "request," which is a mandatory parameter for calling the API. However, I don't understand why symbol, side, ordertype, and qty are also mandatory, as they are individual parameters used to place a single order. To clarify further, if I have a block of orders and pass it in the array, let's say there are 3 orders (sell, sell limit, buy market) for 3 different cryptocurrencies, what should I put for symbol? Since it's mandatory, what about side, ordertype, and qty?

```
https://bybit-exchange.github.io/docs/v5/order/batch-place
```